# How do I optimize my deployment of a C# SQL Server Website on IIS 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, web-deployment, iis-8

When I deploy my website to live, it takes in excess of one minute for the website to come back up.  This is certainly not my area of expertise, but I don't know where to look to figure out what to do to optimize this.

Project Details

1. C#  Web Forms with SQL Server and the .Net 4.0 Framework.
2. CMS pages are created by another project, and these pages exist in the same live folder as the main project pages.

Deployment Process

1. Copy the live folder.
2. In IIS Basic Settings, point to the newly copied folder.
3. I typically click "Restart" on the website.
4. If it takes way too long, I sometimes recycle the App Pool.
5. Empty the original live folder (except for the two main CMS folders)
6. Copy in the code produced from the C# Project.
7. Copy the files from the copied folder into the original live folder.  (There are some CMS pages scattered throughout the project, and that's the purpose of this step.  I do NOT overwrite any files in this step, so it just picks up any files that aren't already in the original file.)
8. In Basic Settings, switch back to the original live folder.
9. Restart the Website?  Recycle the App Pool?

Whenever I switch to a different folder, it usually takes over one minute but less than two. Still, this seems a bit too long.  By switching twice, that means 3-4 minutes where the site is spinning for our users.

So, what am I doing wrong?  (I know I need to update the project and such, but this is where it is today.)

Comment: Without knowledge of what the web-site is *doing* in that time, this is almost impossible to answer; does it load a lot of data into memory? Is it compiling all the pages ahead of time? very hard for us to know - it isn't our code :/

Comment: @MarcGravell I assume that Team City has compiled everything already.  I don't believe it has to load much data.  How can I answer those questions for you?  Is there a way for me to tell what it's doing?

Comment: As far as the mechanics of updating the site, have you considered using [Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/use-the-web-deployment-tool)?

Comment: @chadnt No, I wasn't aware of that.  I will look into it.